# How to unmount external disk with one click (AMPLibrar issue)?

Tags: ios, finder, disk-utility, external-disk

After an update from 10.4.6 to 12.2.1 The MacOS has a new feature: Sometimes it is not possible to unmount an external disk by the click on the unmount symbol in the finder

[image]

Instead, the Mac now says sometimes the disk cannot be unmounted. Maybe it is a new game?

Then I have to do

```
lsof /Volume/MyExternalDisk
```

to find the process clinging to the external disk, like

```
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
AMPLibrar 40821     me    3r   REG   1,12     5925 2381095 /Volumes/MyExternalDisk/Music Library.musiclibrary/Library.musicdb
```

and kill that process manually.

I know, the new MacOS 12.2.1 wants to play with me sometimes, but sometimes I just want to unmount the external disk with one click on

[image]

So is there a way to do so? To suppress that process? To make sure that process is not running?

Comment: I haven't had need to test it since 'Music' took over from iTunes, but for many other reasons, it was always better to keep the library databases on the boot drive, even if the actual media files are elsewhere. I've only one Mac with the new Music structure, though it doesn't use remote media, which now appears to have put Music in its own folder yet left all of iTunes where it was… so I'm reasonably sure the same rules would apply.

Comment: I am sorry, but what you wrote will not help me to fix this annoyance.

Comment: Moving the database to the boot drive would mitigate its being in use from preventing your external drive unmounting.

Comment: What are you talking about. What database? I am just plugging in the stick, use `mplayer` to listen to music that is on the stick, and nothing else. I do nothing else than listening to music files located on that stick using `mplayer`. What database do you mean...?

Comment: The database you listed in your original question

Comment: You mean that `library.musicdb`? I have no idea what this file is. I have no idea what this process is. I have no idea what that process triggers. I want to avoid/remove that process. I do not want that process to run. I have no idea what this process is. It only prevents the disk from being unmounted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135130/discussion-between-alex-and-tetsujin).